# msbuild community task and Svn commit

Tags: svn, msbuild

I'm currently using the tigris open source project MSBuild Community Task and I have some trouble with the SvnCommit Task. 
I don't really know how to use the Targets attribute 
I have this line in my project :

```
<SvnCommit Username="myName" Password="myPsswd" LocalPath="$(myPath)" ToolPath="$(SvnPath)" Targets="myFile.zip"/>
```

and I have an error : "c:\blabla" - which is a part of $(myPath) - is not a working copy; svn : Can't open file 'c:\blabla.svn\Entries"

If someone has some ideas, they are welcome !

maybe sould I use the RepositoryPath attribute ?

Answer (score 4):

ok I have found my problem and it's so silly that I really apologize for the noise on this site. by the way if it can help someone who encounters same pb...

so the problem was my "Target" attribute ! I had to use a ItemGroup : 
so I add the following lines  in my project

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ToCommit Include="$(myPath)/myFile.zip" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and changed the task :

```
<SvnCommit Username="myName" Password="myPsswd" LocalPath="$(myPath)" ToolPath="$(SvnPath)" Targets="@(ToCommit)"/>
```